# Python - Pandas 4D DataFrame: manipulation (supposedly shaping and reshaping) for visual representation - working Matlab reference script provided

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matlab, matplotlib

**Starting point:**
My starting point is a dataFrame as the one reported below:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C | ... | Column D | ...
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ... | -------- | ...
| a1       | b1       | c1       | ... | d01      | ...
| a1       | b1       | c2       | ... | d02      | ...
| a1       | b1       | c3       | ... | d03      | ...
|          | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a1       | b2       | c1       | ... | d04      | ...
| a1       | b2       | c2       | ... | d05      | ...
| a1       | b2       | c3       | ... | d06      | ...
|          | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a1       | b3       | c1       | ... | d07      | ...
| a1       | b3       | c2       | ... | d08      | ...
| a1       | b3       | c3       | ... | d09      | ...
| -------- | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a2       | b1       | c1       | ... | d10      | ...
| a2       | b1       | c2       | ... | d11      | ...
| a2       | b1       | c3       | ... | d12      | ...
|          | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a2       | b2       | c1       | ... | d13      | ...
| a2       | b2       | c2       | ... | d14      | ...
| a2       | b2       | c3       | ... | d15      | ...
|          | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a2       | b3       | c1       | ... | d16      | ...
| a2       | b3       | c2       | ... | d17      | ...
| a2       | b3       | c3       | ... | d18      | ...
| -------- | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a3       | b1       | c1       | ... | d19      | ...
| a3       | b1       | c2       | ... | d20      | ...
| a3       | b1       | c3       | ... | d21      | ...
|          | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a3       | b2       | c1       | ... | d22      | ...
| a3       | b2       | c2       | ... | d23      | ...
| a3       | b2       | c3       | ... | d24      | ...
|          | -------- |          | ... |          | ...
| a3       | b3       | c1       | ... | d25      | ...
| a3       | b3       | c2       | ... | d26      | ...
| a3       | b3       | c3       | ... | d27      | ...
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ... | -------- | ...
| .        | .        | .        | ... | .        | ...
| .        | .        | .        | ... | .        | ...
| .        | .        | .        | ... | .        | ...
```

**additional note on the data structure** which may aid in then better understand my goal later on:
this is a 4D structure:

- columns A, B, C are independent variables. I assumed in the example that each independent variables has 3 different values and I tried to show the structure of the datFrame by using some separations.
- column D is an example of a dependent variable.
  for their nature, the independent variables constitute a grid on whose points a value of the scalar is defined.

**Specific Goal:**
My goal is to adequately manipulate the dataFrame and produce representation of a 3D sub-space at a specific value of an arbitrary independent variable. In other words: I wish to fix one of the independent variables and then plot the value of the dependent variable onto a grid given by the remaining independent variables.

**Final Output Reference**
I am aiming at a representation of the same fashion as the one reported in the example #2 here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-pcolormesh-in-python/

**MatLab solution**
I have a rather basic, but functioning, solution to this in MatLab that leverage two simple functions: reshape and squeeze. I was hoping to have an equally easy life in python with pandas data frames.
I have minor experience with python and pandas data frames, and I feel that I lack some information to fill the gap between the two environments.
After spending several hours trying to overcome issues I am here asking for support :)

**In matlab:**

```
Note: Matlab     previous example
      Z        : A
      Zvar     : B
      PV       : C
      PVvar    : not present
      scalar   : D

%Script starts
    TableName = "chemtable.LeNon1.prem_Kn.ascii.dat";
    dimZ     = 256;
    dimZvar  = 2;
    dimPV    = 256;
    dimPVvar = 0;
    
    data     = readtable(TableName);
    data_a   =table2array(data);
    
    % prepare mixture fraction (A)
    Z_v = data_a(:,1);                          % Z is at column 1
    Z_r = reshape(Z_v,[dimZ,dimZvar,dimPV]);
    Z = squeeze(Z_r(:,1,:));                    % select index of 3rd dimension cut plane
    % prepare progresse variable (C)
    PV_v = data_a(:,3);                         % PV is at column 3
    PV_r = reshape(PV_v,[dimZ,dimZvar,dimPV]);
    PV = squeeze(PV_r(:,1,:));
    
    scalar_v = data_a(:,4);                     % 4 is a random number pointing to a generic variable
    scalar_r = reshape(scalar_v,[dimZ,dimZvar,dimPV]);
    scalar = squeeze(scalar_r(:,1,:));
    
    figure;
    hold on;
    title('');
    xlabel('Z');
    ylabel('PV');
    ax = gca;
    ax.FontSize = 13;
    surf(Z,PV,scalar);
    shading flat;
```

I probably miss sone key point about python and how to adequately manipulate dataFrames to reproduce what I got in matlab. Any help and indication of specific method, functions or general topic of interest is very welcome.

Thanks in advance!